# How can I know whether the model is converged or failed to converge in lme4 without warning message in r?

Tags: r, multi-level, convergence

duplicated

For example,
I can assess whether this multilevel model is a singular fit or not by
using `isSingular()` function.

Likewise, is there any way that I can know whether this model is converged or failed to be converged?

My advisor said, if the model is failed to converge, the standard error will not be estimated. However, although the below failed to converge, a standard error seems to be estimated.

is there any good indicator that this model is converged or failed to converge? (other than noticing a warning message)

I am using the `lme4` package and `lmer()` function.

For example,  there is an example of failed convergence multilevel model

```
library(lme4)
read.table(textConnection("duration season  sites   effect
                          4d    mon s1  7305.91
                          4d    mon s2  856.297
                          4d    mon s3  649.93
                          4d    mon s1  10121.62
                          4d    mon s2  5137.85
                          4d    mon s3  3059.89
                          4d    mon s1  5384.3
                          4d    mon s2  5014.66
                          4d    mon s3  3378.15
                          4d    post    s1  6475.53
                          4d    post    s2  2923.15
                          4d    post    s3  554.05
                          4d    post    s1  7590.8
                          4d    post    s2  3888.01
                          4d    post    s3  600.07
                          4d    post    s1  6717.63
                          4d    post    s2  1542.93
                          4d    post    s3  1001.4
                          4d    pre s1  9290.84
                          4d    pre s2  2199.05
                          4d    pre s3  1149.99
                          4d    pre s1  5864.29
                          4d    pre s2  4847.92
                          4d    pre s3  4172.71
                          4d    pre s1  8419.88
                          4d    pre s2  685.18
                          4d    pre s3  4133.15
                          7d    mon s1  11129.86
                          7d    mon s2  1492.36
                          7d    mon s3  1375
                          7d    mon s1  10927.16
                          7d    mon s2  8131.14
                          7d    mon s3  9610.08
                          7d    mon s1  13732.55
                          7d    mon s2  13314.01
                          7d    mon s3  4075.65
                          7d    post    s1  11770.79
                          7d    post    s2  4254.88
                          7d    post    s3  753.2
                          7d    post    s1  11324.95
                          7d    post    s2  5133.76
                          7d    post    s3  2156.2
                          7d    post    s1  12103.76
                          7d    post    s2  3143.72
                          7d    post    s3  2603.23
                          7d    pre s1  13928.88
                          7d    pre s2  3208.28
                          7d    pre s3  8015.04
                          7d    pre s1  11851.47
                          7d    pre s2  6815.31
                          7d    pre s3  8478.77
                          7d    pre s1  13600.48
                          7d    pre s2  1219.46
                          7d    pre s3  6987.5
                          "),header=T)->dat1

lmer(effect ~ duration + (1+duration|sites) +(1+duration|season),
                                  data=dat1)
```

This generates error
Warning message:
Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -2.3e+01

however, it seems that standard error seems to be estimated, although it is failed to converge.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: effect ~ duration + (1 + duration | sites) + (1 + duration |      season)
   Data: dat1

REML criterion at convergence: 969

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0515 -0.6676  0.0075  0.5333  3.2161 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 sites    (Intercept) 8033602  2834         
          duration7d  1652488  1285     1.00
 season   (Intercept)       0     0         
          duration7d  1175980  1084      NaN
 Residual             5292365  2301         
Number of obs: 54, groups:  sites, 3; season, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 4183.896   1695.252    2.008   2.468    0.132  
duration7d  3265.641   1155.357    3.270   2.827    0.060 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr)
duration7d 0.520 
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

(the above data and code is Not my model,
I copied and pasted this data and code from one of stack overflow question.)

To sum up, my question is

1. is there any clear function or way to notify whether this function is converged or failed converge, other than noticing warning message

(like, assessing singularity, isSingular() function gives clear indication)

2. Why standard error still estimated while the model is failed to converge?

the ultimate goal is for my simulation study, I will calculate the convergence rate.

Comment: In general, if a warning is not enough, you can turn a warning into an error with `options(warn=2)`, which means the operation will end so you should not get any standard errors or other output. Just remember to set warnings back to 1 afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My advisor said, if the model is failed to converge, the standard error will not be estimated. However, although the below failed to converge, a standard error seems to be estimated.

The model you showed **has** converged. You know this because of the message:

```
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
```

If it had not converged you would see a warning like:

```
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

However it has converged to a singular fit as shown in the next line:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

> is there any clear function or way to notify whether this function is converged or failed converge, other than noticing warning message

I use the following helper function for that:

```
# helper function
# Has the model converged ?

hasConverged <- function (mm) {
  
  if ( !inherits(mm, "merMod")) stop("Error: must pass a lmerMod object")
  
  retval <- NULL
  
  if(is.null(unlist(mm@optinfo$conv$lme4))) {
    retval = 1
  }
  else {
    if (isSingular(mm)) {
      retval = 0
    } else {
      retval = -1
    }
  }
  return(retval)
}
```

which returns 1 if the model converged *normally* ie not to a singular fit, 0 if it converges to a singular fit and -1 if it fails to converge. Another approach is to promote the warnings to errors as per the comment by @SamR:

> In general, if a warning is not enough, you can turn a warning into an error with options(warn=2), which means the operation will end so you should not get any standard errors or other output. Just remember to set warnings back to 1 afterwards.

Moving on:

> Why standard error still estimated while the model is failed to converge?

Well, as mentioned above, it has converged, and your advisor is wrong here:

> My advisor said, if the model is failed to converge, the standard error will not be estimated.

If the model fails to converge it will output the estimates obtained on the last iteration before it gave up.

Comment: Not bad, but I would change `!class(mm)[1] == "lmerMod"` to `!inherits(mm, "merMod")`

Comment: Thanks ! Changed ! Is that to pick up models that are fitted with packages such as `lmerTest` ?

Comment: no, it picks up `glmer` fits as well (and it's a little bit more general/principled -- I guess it could work with `lmerTest` objects as well, although I hadn't thought about it ...)

Comment: @BenBolker It seems that it also picks up models fitted with `lmerTest:` :)
`lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1| Subject), sleepstudy) %>% inherits("merMod")`
evaluates to TRUE :)

Comment: Thanks for this information! however, This model generated errors as followings:  Warning message:
Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -2.3e+01. Although I got this warning message from this model, is it NOT fail to converge? I am confused.  I copied and pasted  the fail converge error message in the above, but I think people missed that...

Comment: If a ran the following code ```hasConverged(lmer(effect ~ duration + (1+duration|sites) +(1+duration|season),
+                   data=dat1))```, it gives the results like this: ```[1] 0
Warning message:
Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -2.3e+01.``` 0 means it is NOT failed to converge, but the warning message seems to be contradictory. How can I interpret this?